# password_verify for Phalcon Encryption Library

Tags: php, encryption, password-protection, phalcon, password-encryption

Hello there,
I'm trying to setup a basic login with phalcon with it's encryption library
Whereas
the following code returns the false

```
$crypt = new Phalcon\Crypt();
$string = 'password';
$enc_password = $crypt->encrypt($string, ENCRYPTION_KEY);
$dec_password = $crypt->decrypt($enc_password, ENCRYPTION_KEY);
if($string == $dec_password){
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

this condition returns false, whereas if both `$string` & `$dec_password` echo out **password**, php function `stcmp` returns -24. Generated encryption is as below

**¡ØŠ7¯r¿ëæ5.=ã´M‡ÖŸ‚sH]‚­)G¼ÂÆÂ]ªü¥»Íµ–¾T]oDÝÔYf}**

And I'd like to go with this kind of encryption if this problem is fixed.
Thank You

Answer (score 1):

The password should be hashed which is a one way function, so I don't seed the necessity of decrypting the password

Go ahead and refer to the vokuro project which shows you how to handle this

https://github.com/phalcon/vokuro/blob/master/app/controllers/SessionController.php#L86

https://github.com/phalcon/vokuro/blob/master/app/library/Auth/Auth.php#L34

That being said, the following should work:

```
$crypt->setKey('¡ØŠ7¯r¿ëæ5.=ã´M‡ÖŸ‚sH]‚­)G¼ÂÆÂ]ªü¥»Íµ–¾T]oDÝÔYf}')
```

https://github.com/phalcon/vokuro/blob/master/app/config/services.php#L97

```
return $this->security->checkHash($string, $enc_password)
```